# How to expand an integral of a function as a function of integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Consider an unspecified smooth norm $|\vec{y}| = f(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider the following integral
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(a_1(x),a_2(x),...,a_n(x)) dx$$
where $\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n$ are smooth real functions with compact support in $[0,L]$.

In the limit $L \to 0$ we can then approximate the integral to lowest order by
$I \approx f(a_1(x_0),a_2(x_0),...)L$, where $x_0 \in [0,L]$. However, we can also rewrite this approximation using $a_i(x_0) L \approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty a_i dx$ so that
$$I \approx f\left(\frac{1}{L}\int_{-\infty}^\infty a_1 dx,\frac{1}{L}\int_{-\infty}^\infty a_2 dx,...\right) L =  f\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty a_1 dx,\int_{-\infty}^\infty a_2 dx,...\right) $$
where I have used the scalable property of the norm.

What is stated above is the integral up to $\mathcal{O}(L)$ order expressed in terms of simple functionals of $a_i$ and without reference to $L$. I am looking for something similar to general, $\mathcal{O}(L^n)$ order.

So my question is:

*Is there a way to obtain an asymptotic expansion of $I$ for $L \to 0$, so that*

1) *$L$ is not stated anywhere in the expansion similarly to the expression above, and*

2) *the expansion is stated only in terms of the norm, its derivatives, and infinite integrals **not** involving the norm such as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x a_i dx, \int_{-\infty}^\infty a_i'' dx,...$?*